# Как ввести компьютер в домен(AD) который установлен виртуально через HyperV

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, hyper-v

Есть компьютер с виртуальной машиной(HyperV), на виртуальной машине установлен Windows Server 2022, AD, DNS Server.
Есть ноутбук который нужно ввести в домен.
Компьютер и ноутбук соединены в одну сеть через Wi Fi
Виртуальный сервер находиться в другой подсети.
Собственно вопрос как ввести ноутбук в домен?

Answer (score 0):

В такой конфигурации я вижу только один выход - VPN. Для начала нужно виртуальную NIC сервера подключить к NIC компьютера, тогда ноутбук будет в одной физической сети с сервером и должен его "увидеть" (это нужно для установки VPN-соединения). После этого на сервере создать VPN-сервер, и подключить к нему ноутбук. Таким образом ноутбук подключится к доменной сети сервера.